# noatime does not take effect

Tags: filesystem, fstab

Here is the line for my root partition in `fstab`:

```
UUID=ab358046-2feb-4837-8827-0a98cd22a899 /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

and it's been like this for as far as I can remember. However when I click on files in Thunar and check their "last accessed" I see correct last access times. Why is this?